# Update existing moment locale when changing global value

Tags: angular, momentjs

As of 2.8.0, changing the global locale doesn't affect existing instances.

How do I update the locale for existing moment instances without re-rendering the page

```
moment.locale('fr');
var m = moment(1316116057189);
m.fromNow(); // il y a une heure

moment.locale('en');
m.fromNow(); // il y a une heure
moment(1316116057189).fromNow(); // an hour ago
```

How do I update the locale for m after it has been created? Or link the locale for m to the global moment locale?

For example:

I have a service

```
// Language service
moment.locale('en-GB')


updateLanguage(lang) {
   moment.locale(lang);
}
```

and a component with

```
// Component

this.timeLabel = moment(this.event.time).fromNow(); // an hour ago
```

When I call `languageService.updateLang('fr');` the value of timeLabel needs to change so that it uses the updated locale. However it stays the same.

I could subscribe to a `Subject` but I have hundreds of variables like this across the application

Comment: See [Changing locales locally](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) section of momentjs documentation to see how to change locale for existing moment instances.